# Pushing to history gives a blank page instead of the queried page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working on my little React app. At some point, I need to push history to open a new page (well, actually, putting parameters in the URL).

However, when I push to the history, I stumble upon a blank page, which is not what I want (obviously).

I tried searching what could be the issue, but I didn't find anything.

Here is the code of my router and the push.

```
onClick={() => {
            this.props.history.push({
              pathname: this.props.history.location.pathname
            });
          }}
```

```
export default function EnglishComparators () {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();

  i18n.changeLanguage('en');

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/checking-accounts" component={CheckingComparator} />
      <Route exact path="/savings-accounts" component={SavingsComparator} />
      <Route exact path="/gic-accounts" component={GICComparator} />
      <Route exact path="/robo-advisors" component={RoboAdvisorsComparator} />
      <Route exact path="/brokerage-accounts" component={BrokersComparator} />
      <Route exact path="/credit-cards" component={CreditCardsComparator} />
      <Route path="/" component={FrenchComparators} />
    </Switch>
  );
}


export default function FrenchComparators () {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();

  i18n.changeLanguage('fr');

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/comptes-chèque" component={CheckingComparator} />
      <Route exact path="/comptes-épargnes" component={SavingsComparator} />
      <Route exact path="/comptes-cpg" component={GICComparator} />
      <Route exact path="/robot-conseillers" component={RoboAdvisorsComparator} />
      <Route exact path="/courtiers-en-ligne" component={BrokersComparator} />
      <Route exact path="/cartes-de-crédit" component={CreditCardsComparator} />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake in my previous answer and I got a little bit deep in the problem.

I created this sandbox to simulate the same approach that you are doing.

https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-example-using-react-router-2yovb?file=/src/App.js

I don't know if it makes sense to `push` the history with `pathname: this.props.history.location.pathname` once that you are getting the same location that the user are.

Comment: Still, I tried it in my app with your code and it doesn't work... I don't see why.

Comment: It is hard to say where is the problem without checking the complete block of the application. Try toi check if you have the right structured needed by `react-router`. And attention for the component tree to use the hooks, as I did in the example.